# Image keeps disappearing once scrolled past (mobile)

Tags: html, css

**UPDATE** This is only happening on IOS devices.

I have started to experience the problem once I added:

`overflow-y: scroll; & -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

am I adding it in the wrong place? :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 0;
 overflow-x: hidden;
position: relative;
**overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;**
}
```

Here is an example:

(The figure with the umbrella is an image added over the top)

**Before Scroll**

[image: before scroll]

**After Scroll**

[image: after scroll]

Originally I thought my image was too large so I've shrunk it right down to 59kb right now and it is still having the error.
Without the touch scrolling I can't seem to configure a smooth scrolling experience for mobile.

[Website](https://www.bysteveroe.com/)

Comment: Seems like the div that contains the images decreases in height, or another white div scrolls over it

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce your problem, works fine on my pc? on my smartphone the image seems fixed tho.

Comment: problem only occurs on mobile, I've also just found out it seems to only happen on IOS and not android so I think it might be the touch code

Comment: when I run it in chrome I can not see the `overflow` in css:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThQ1s.png

Comment: problem sorted, it was because the background image was fixed, it seemed to conflict with the overflow-y